# In MySQL, how to execute two different SELECT statements depending on a condition?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

```
SET @input1=123;
SET @input2='foobar';


IF @inout1>0 THEN

SELECT
    @result := col12
FROM
    table1
WHERE
   col11=@input1;

ELSE IF @input2 != ''

SELECT
    @result := col21
FROM
    table2
WHERE
    col22=@input2;

END
```

Basically depending on if `@input1` or `@input2` is set and if the set value satisfy certain condition, one of the two SELECT statements should be run. But I just couldn't get it to work with IF THEN ELSE statement in MySQL. What should be the right syntax?

Comment: Please, tag your MySQL version.

Comment: IF statement is for stored routines as well as most of other flow control statements. You have to declare the routine for IF-THEN-ELSE-END IF inside.

Comment: In MariaDB you can use IF-THEN-ELSE-END-IF logic and other SQL/PSM constructs without the need for stored routines - just put the logic inside the [`BEGIN NOT ATOMIC ... END`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/begin-end/) syntax. Just saying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM ( full text of query 1 )
WHERE (condition 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM ( full text of query 2 )
WHERE (condition 2)
  AND NOT (condition 1)
```

Neither condition must give NULL (due to NULL in field/variable values) in NOT.

Outer SELECTs for each separate subquery in UNION may be excess if separate queries are not complex.

For the code shown in the question it will be

```
SET @input1=123;
SET @input2='foobar';

SELECT @result := col12
FROM   table1
WHERE  col11 = @input1
  AND  @input1 > 0

UNION ALL

SELECT @result := col21
FROM   table2
WHERE  col22=@input2
  AND  @input2 != ''
  AND  COALESCE(@input1, -1) <= 0; /* prevent ejecting by NULL */
```

Comment: What is the significance of `AND  COALESCE(@input1, -1) <= 0;`? I don't understand the comment. Thanks.

Comment: @qazwsx If `@input1` is NULL, both conditions (`@input1>0` and `@input1<=0`) are false. COALESCE prevents it.